# Isomorphic Direct Summand

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm reading the proof of the Krull-Schmidt theorem for modules which is below
[image]

I think I might have a misconception here but if we know that $U_1 \xrightarrow{\cong} V_j$ via $f$, don't we immediately know that $U_1 \oplus U_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_k \cong V_j \oplus U_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_k$ via $f \oplus Id_{U_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_k}$ so we have $M \cong V_j \oplus U_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_k$?

Why do we have to prove that $U_1 \cong V_j$ in a way such that $M \cong V_j \oplus U_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_k$?

Thank you all.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Maybe it should read as '*so that*' instead of 'such that'.

Comment: @Berci thank you for your confirmation, I thought the same thing too.  Another reason I can think of is maybe the author wants to say $M = U_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_k = V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_l$ and not just isomorphic, then he tries to show that $M = V_j \oplus U_2 \cdots \oplus U_k$.